# Знаки препинания в текстах разговорной речи

Tags: пунктуация

Как расставить запятые и кавычки в  разговорных диалогах и фразах:

- А вообще, как дела?
- В смысле?
- В смысле, на "личном фронте".

Или

У него одни опилки, в смысле,  в голове.

Answer (score 2):

Угрюм Веселов, в чём вопрос? Запятые расставлены верно. Первый пример оформляете, естественно, диалогом (каждая реплика образует абзац и начинается с тире), второй - прямой речью в кавычках, если, конечно, это одинокая реплика. Проблема в чём?

Comment: Посмотрите другие вопросы у этого автора. Они все подобного уровня.  И ещё у полудюжины авторов, как две капли на него похожих. "Вопрос" в том, чтобы регулярно задавать вопросы - и получить виртуальную медальку.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, больше не ловлюсь.

Comment: Я не знаю никаких виртуальных медалек , мне не нужна никакая репутация. Вы  здесь критикуете меня абсолютно беспочвенно. Я все вопросы задаю, потому что мне это действительно нужно и интересно. Всем отвечающим - спасибо!

Comment: Угрюм Веселов, есть подозрение, что вы систематически используете сообщество для проверки домашних заданий. Большинству отвечающих этого добра на работе хватает, никто здесь не обязан это делать. Так потрудитесь хотя бы точно и однозначно формулировать вопросы.

Comment: Я даже не знаю, как можно еще точнее и однозначнее  формулировать свои вопросы. Мне 34 года, я уже очень давно закончил школу и техникум. Работа моя тоже никак не связана с правилами русского языка. Я задаю вопросы исключительно для собственного кругозора. Хотя по русскому языку у меня в школе всегда была твердая четверка, сейчас  я понял что пунктуацию я вообще почти забыл. Если вы считаете, что не обязаны отвечать, то, пожалуйста, вас никто не заставляет